# R : Aggregate data by two variables and count the number of times the value of a third variable appears

Tags: r

I have this type of database in an Excel file

```
   UGA     Date     Product
  A      05/2018   AM
  Z.     06/2019   BX
  X.     01/2020   AM
  M.     02/2017   AM
  B.     03/2019   AM/BX
  M.     04/2018   BX
```

The variable Product can take three types of value: AM, BX or AM/BX

And I would like to get this type of table by using R code

```
  UGA   Date      Nb_AM   Nb_BX
  A     01/2017   4       14
  A     02/2017   5       17
  A     03/2017   2       24
  B     01/2017   3       35
  B     02/2017   10      42
  B     03/2017   24      2
```

I want to aggregate the data by UGA and by date and create two new columns Nb_AM and Nb_BX and I don't want to display the column "product" anymore

With Nb_AM corresponding to the number of apparition of "AM" and "AM/BX" for a date and an UGA

And Nb_BX corresponding to the number of "BX" and "AM/BX" for a date and an UGA

I think I should use the aggregate command but I have no idea how to use it
Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your sample data a bit to include 2 values in the same month. Let me know if this works. If you already have the data read in with readxl or alternatively read_csv, skip everything `separate` and earlier.

```r
library(tidyverse)

read_delim("   UGA     Date     Product
  A      05/2018   AM
  A.     05/2018   AM/BX
  Z.     06/2019   BX
  X.     01/2020   AM
  M.     02/2017   AM
  B.     03/2005   AM/BX
  M.     04/20189  BX", delim = "\\n") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_trim)) %>%
  separate(1, into = c("UGA", "Date", "Product"), sep = " +")  %>%
  mutate(UGA = str_remove(UGA, "\\.")) %>%
  group_by(UGA, Date, Product) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Product, values_from = count, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Nb_AM = AM + `AM/BX`,
         Nb_BX = BX + `AM/BX`) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(UGA, Date, starts_with("Nb"))
```