# Aggregate data by two variables and count the number of times the value of a third variable appears

Tags: r

I have this type of database in an Excel file

```
UGA     Date     Product
A      05/2018   AM
Z.     06/2019   BX
X.     01/2020   AM
M.     02/2017   AM
B.     03/2019   AM/BX
M.     04/2018   BX
```

The variable Product can take three types of value: AM, BX or AM/BX

And I would like to get this type of table by using R code

```
UGA   Date      Nb_AM   Nb_BX
A     01/2017   4       14
A     02/2017   5       17
A     03/2017   2       24
B     01/2017   3       35
B     02/2017   10      42
B     03/2017   24      2
```

I want to aggregate the data by UGA and by date and create two new columns Nb_AM and Nb_BX and I don't want to display the column "product" anymore

With Nb_AM corresponding to the number of apparition of "AM" and "AM/BX" for a date and an UGA

And Nb_BX corresponding to the number of "BX" and "AM/BX" for a date and an UGA

I think I should use the aggregate command but I have no idea how to use it Could you please help me?

For the moment I just have this code :

```
 am <- read_excel("C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Bureau/Master data/Mémoire data analyst/Bases de 
 données/Ventes/AM_per_UGA.xlsx")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R : Aggregate data by two variables and count the number of times the value of a third variable appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071491/r-aggregate-data-by-two-variables-and-count-the-number-of-times-the-value-of-a)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using

```
library(dplyr)

am |> 
    group_by(UGA , Date) |> 
    summarise(Nb_AM = sum(grepl("AM" , Product , fixed = T)) , Nb_BX = sum(grepl("BX" , Product , fixed = T)))|>
    ungroup()
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  UGA   Date    Nb_AM Nb_BX
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <int>
1 A     05/2018     1     0
2 B.    03/2019     1     1
3 M.    02/2017     1     0
4 M.    04/2018     0     1
5 X.    01/2020     1     0
6 Z.    06/2019     0     1
```

Comment: thank you very much but I have an error : Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `Nb_AM = sum(grepl("ABILIFY MAINTENA", Product, fixed = T))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: UGA = "01BEL", Date = 2018-03-01.
Caused by error in `is.factor()`:
! object 'Product' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>         |> ungroup()
Error: unexpected '|>' in "        |>"

Comment: What is this string `ABILIFY MAINTENA`?

Comment: yes sorry, in fact in my database AM is ABILIFY MAINTENA and BX is BRINTELLIX

Comment: Would you `dput(head(am))` ?